# How do I print console output from a method of another class to Winform Listbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am currently making a Windows form application. What it does is that it takes a 2D array as input and executes a method (say M). My form has a listbox which I would like to use as a Message Log. The method M when called (using a button present in the form) prints various lines to the Console using Console.WriteLine to show the current progress. I want to get those lines to show up in the listbox present in my form as messages so that the current progress is known. How can I achieve that? Any help will be appreciated!

I also found the code below from an exisiting answer on stackoverflow which derives a new class from TextWriter. But I am not sure if it serves the purpose I am looking for.

```
public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    private ListBox list;
    private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    public ListBoxWriter(ListBox list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        content.Append(value);
        if (value == '\n')
        {
            list.Items.Add(content.ToString());
            content = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need access to the instance of the form where you want the output to go.  So you need to pass the instance between classes.  See my two form project where I pass the instance of form1 to form2.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?force_isolation=true

Comment: Using the console as a mechanism to communicate between two forms is far harder work, and more unreliable, then just coding the app to have one form use the other directly

Comment: Change `Console.WriteLine()` to `listBox1.Items.Add()`?...what's the issue?

Comment: Idle_Mind The issue is not that I can't print the text to my Listbox. The problem is how to access the live text being printed by a method of another class to the console when it is called inside my form.

Comment: If a CLASS is generating the text, then make it raise a CUSTOM EVENT to pass out the information.  Then you can have multiple subscribers  to that event and each receiver do something different with the information.

Comment: Idle_Mind Thanks for your comment. But the thing is I am a newbie in C# and know very less of it. Could you please give an example with the code?

Comment: So is "method M" actually in a class other than the Form?  I assume the Form is creating an instance of the class containing method M?  Having that setup described or in your posted code will help up give you a good example.